# Transform Curved Line into Straight Line

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have a distribution of scores that is currently somewhat curved, reflecting bunching of values at certain ranges. I would like to flatten this curve out so that what is left is a straight, declining line between 0 and 100. I have no idea where to start to make this transformation.

I have attached an image of the data with a simple polynomial regression run against the LOG of the number in each range. I have also attached the raw data.

- 1,3222266983662
- 2,1033363424063
- 3,572507179617
- 4,397837772260
- 5,272702109150
- 6,214860801517
- 7,159527368431
- 8,124812092026
- 9,106198945022
- 10,94011464982
- 11,85086955747
- 12,67329749341
- 13,60286421903
- 14,53239501199
- 15,47421127631
- 16,45493388624
- 17,36511487697
- 18,35621046952
- 19,31365292955
- 20,28056229522
- 21,29220769583
- 22,28349820803
- 23,24257887309
- 24,21204595564
- 25,24578641841
- 26,21733803769
- 27,18983788324
- 28,23703186842
- 29,20212830681
- 30,15884718441
- 31,14433647636
- 32,16369809127
- 33,14489654952
- 34,16393976949
- 35,13687318215
- 36,13564259597
- 37,12669104529
- 38,12842214983
- 39,14316929455
- 40,9916745113
- 41,13982804512
- 42,10209890144
- 43,10325057441
- 44,12323446658
- 45,11991480181
- 46,13137405614
- 47,11041316099
- 48,13102375158
- 49,9455056963
- 50,10365710458
- 51,10903436421
- 52,8385862967
- 53,10343275556
- 54,12082021807
- 55,8339347239
- 56,12849613841
- 57,8071241272
- 58,11282598249
- 59,4443425203
- 60,4994315750
- 61,6428917730
- 62,3838092793
- 63,5511016583
- 64,4697686488
- 65,11547998521
- 66,6045899730
- 67,978162537
- 68,8007329393
- 69,7376618323
- 70,459680294
- 71,10005522273
- 72,2288139372
- 73,629750530
- 74,277579404
- 75,169682480
- 76,116877417
- 77,111195051
- 78,72702965
- 79,72139333
- 80,57057491
- 81,50848577
- 82,45481652
- 83,40487540
- 84,36464123
- 85,31929677
- 86,27622920
- 87,21951750
- 88,19000403
- 89,15726659
- 90,13170733
- 91,11529975
- 92,10763335
- 93,9549124
- 94,8900646
- 95,7472734
- 96,5010478
- 97,2359271
- 98,929536
- 99,173419
- 100,5

[Curved to Straight Conversion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuyZE.jpg)

Comment: Hi @user2648990 welcome to Math. SE. Can you show your attempts?

Comment: I am impressed by your patience while typing this out

Comment: Unfortunately, this is way out of my league. The two data scientists at our company responsible for this project left for their own startup last week unannounced so here we are.